# Using an entry box to set a variable's value and display it in a Label using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to ask the user to input a number (in this example, they need to enter a number of minutes into the `minEntry` box). I want to take this number and use it to set multiple variable values by multiplying this value with other numbers. Then i want to take this value and have it displayed in the `sublabel` box within the `__init__` function. Im getting an error message that says `'PageSix' object has no attribute 'peak_rate'`. I sort of know what this means but i have no idea how to solve it.

```
class PageSix(tk.Frame):

    def projected_figures(self):
        global minEntry
        tariff = self.controller.page_get(PageTwo)
        minutes=minEntry.get()
        self.peak_rate = tk.StringVar()
        self.peak_rate.set(0)
        self.off_peak = tk.StringVar()
        self.off_peak.set(0)
        self.line_rental = tk.StringVar()
        self.line_rental.set(0)
        if tariff.current_tariff == "A":
            self.peak_rate.set("Peak Rate: £"+minutes*0.3)
            self.off_peak.set("Off-Peak: £"+minutes*0.05)
            self.line_rental.set("Line Rental: £15")
        elif tariff.current_tariff == "B":
            self.peak_rate.set("Peak Rate: £"+minutes*0.1)
            self.off_peak.set("Off-Peak: £"+minutes*0.02)
            self.line_rental.set("Line Rental: £20")
        else:
            self.peak_rate.set("Peak Rate: £"+minutes*0.9)
            self.off_peak.set("Off-Peak: -")
            self.line_rental.set("Line Rental: £30")

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Account Balance", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        sublabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.peak_rate, font=SMALL_FONT)
        sublabel.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        sublabel2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.off_peak, font=SMALL_FONT)
        sublabel2.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        sublabel3 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.line_rental, font=SMALL_FONT)
        sublabel3.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        minLabel = Label(self, text = 'Enter Minutes: ')
        minEntry = Entry(self)
        minLabel.pack(pady =10, padx = 10, side = TOP, anchor = S)
        minEntry.pack(pady =10, padx = 10, side = TOP, anchor = S)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="View Projected Figures",
                            command=self.projected_figures)
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Menu",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.pack()
```

Also the lines `tariff = self.controller.get_page(PageTwo)` and `if self.current_tariff == "x"` are referring to this class if it can be of any use.

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        self.current_tariff = tk.StringVar()
        self.current_tariff.set("A")

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Current Tariff", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        sublabel = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.current_tariff, font=SMALL_FONT)
        sublabel.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Change Tariff",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSix))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Projected Figures",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSix))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` gets called as soon as you initialize the class and `projected_figures` will be called when you call it.

When you try to initialize `PageSix`, inside of `__init__` at `sublabel` creation line, there is no variable named `self.peak_rate` since `projected_figures` hasn't called yet.

Moving variable creations inside of `__init__` should solve this issue.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    ...
    self.peak_rate = tk.StringVar()
    self.peak_rate.set(0)
    self.off_peak = tk.StringVar()
    self.off_peak.set(0)
    self.line_rental = tk.StringVar()
    self.line_rental.set(0)
    ...
```